# ¿Como truncar decimales?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buenas tardes estoy intentando obtener el resultado de una operación pero el resultado es de unos tres decimales, yo lo estoy convirtiendo el resultado en dos decimales pero quiero obtener exactamente las decimales sin redondear nada, todo  esta operación estoy tratando de que se ejecute de un CASE, adjunto una imagen con los datos que se utilizan. [image: q]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función round

```
select round(123.456, 2, 1)
```

Donde el tercer parametro 1 indica a round que trunque en lugar a redondear, el segundo parametro indica la cantidad de decimales.

[más info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175003(v=sql.90))

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciono lo que comentaste, ademas también influía el orden de la operación